# JasperReports project built with Maven throws error when run on AWS Lambda

Tags: java, maven, aws-lambda, jasper-reports, maven-shade-plugin

When I build a JAVA project containing JasperReport with the help of Maven and its Shade plugin I always get the following error if I run the JAR in AWS Lambda

```
2020-11-24T13:37:52.867+01:00   java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 5
2020-11-24T13:37:52.867+01:00   Handler.reportError caught:
```

If I use Eclipse with the AWS Toolkit everything works as expected... (the same is also mentioned here https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1037691/no-log-messages-eclipse-console).

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.4</version>
<configuration>
  <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
  <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
  <shadedClassifierName>${executable.classifier}</shadedClassifierName>
  <filters>
    <filter>
      <artifact>*:*</artifact>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </filter>
  </filters>
  <artifactSet>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
          <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
          <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
          <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
          <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
          <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </artifactSet>
</configuration>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
          <resource>jasperreports_extension.properties</resource>
          <resource>default.jasperreports.properties/</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer
          implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
        <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
          <mainClass>com.myorg.lambda.demo.GenerateReport</mainClass>
        </transformer>
      </transformers>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is that the whole error?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: what is the configuration of the maven-shade-plugin?

Comment: I added the configuration of the shade plugin.